# Python - Data augmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a python code like below. I want to augment the data in my dataset due to overfitting problem in my model. What I want to do is to augment the data in **train** and **val** values. I tried to do it with `datagen.flow()` function but it gave parameter error.

**My Data:**

```
data_dir = 'data'
os.listdir(data_dir)
tf.data.Dataset??

import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()

batch = data_iterator.next()

data = data.map(lambda x,y: (x/255, y))

scaled_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()

len(data)

train_size = int(len(data)*.7)
val_size = int(len(data)*.2)+1
test_size = int(len(data)*.1)+1

train = data.take(train_size)
val = data.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
test = data.skip(train_size+val_size).take(test_size)
```

**My Model:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout

model = Sequential()

from keras import regularizers
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.9))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.9))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile('adam', loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

**Training:**

```
logdir='logs'
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
hist = model.fit(train, epochs=20, validation_data=val, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

I tried this:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=10, 
                             width_shift_range=0.1, 
                             height_shift_range=0.1, 
                             shear_range=0.15, 
                             zoom_range=0.1, 
                             channel_shift_range=10, 
                             horizontal_flip=True)

datagen.flow(train, batch_size=32)
```

but it gave this error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not
> '_TakeDataset'.

I would appreciate if you can help me how to do this.

Comment: What sort of error?

Comment: @pinegulf TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not '_TakeDataset'.

Answer (score 1):

First of, `ImageDataGenerator` is [deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing), you shouldn't use it:

> **Deprecated**: `tf.keras.preprocessing` APIs do not operate on tensors and
> are not recommended for new code. Prefer loading data with either
> `tf.keras.utils.text_dataset_from_directory` or
> `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`, and then transforming the
> output `tf.data.Dataset` with preprocessing layers. These approaches
> will offer better performance and integration with the broader
> Tensorflow ecosystem. For more information, see the tutorials for
> loading text, loading images, and augmenting images, as well as the
> preprocessing layer guide.

Instead, you can use [preprocessing layers](https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/#image-data-augmentation), or use a library like albumentions.

If you still want to use the ImageDataGenerator with a `tf.data.Dataset`, you should use `map` and `ImageDataGenerator.random_transform` wrapped in a `tf.numpy_function`:

```
train = train.map(
    lambda x, y: (tf.numpy_function(datagen.random_transform, [x], tf.float32), y)
)
```